# getting hostname with IP

Tags: unix, host

how to get hostname with IP without logging into the host

Comment: what technology are you using?

Answer (score 4):

- For Win32, `getnameinfo()`.
- For POSIX, `gethostbyaddr()`.

Making a portable wrapper is left as an exercise. :)

Comment: In Java, there's InetAddress.getHostName().  Does that count? :)

Answer (score 3):

[nslookup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nslookup)

It's on both Windows and Linux.

Answer (score 1):

If you're not using it in code (and you're not, according to an answer you posted, which should have really been an edit to your question :-), it's not a programming question.

But the answer is to use nslookup.

```
Microsoft Windows XP [Version 5.1.2600]
(C) Copyright 1985-2001 Microsoft Corp.

C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator>nslookup www.company.com
Server:  bhadns01.company.com
Address:  9.190.234.35

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    www-int.company.com.cs186.net
Address:  129.42.58.216
Aliases:  www.company.com

C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator>nslookup 129.42.58.216
Server:  bhadns01.company.com
Address:  9.190.234.35

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    www-int.company.com.cs186.net
Address:  129.42.58.216
Aliases:  www.company.com

C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator>
```

Comment: or do it the other way around: nslookup 9.190.234.35

Comment: Thanks, @Z, I had to edit that bit in since I initially misunderstood the question.